# Bad Request accessing Web API from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

Here, I explain my scenario - 
I have 2 projects - **API** (storing the Web API) and **APP** (storing the Xamarin.Forms). I have used EDMX to create Data models from my database in the API project in **API.Models** folder. I want to access the API from the **APP** project and hence have created similar data model classes in my APP project. Things work fine when there are no Foreign Keys present in the model class. As soon as a Foreign Key is added to any of the model classes in API project, consuming the API starts giving me a **"Bad Request error"**

**API.Models Code**

```
namespace API.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Lead
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LeadName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; } //User is another entity in API.Models
    }
}
```

**APP.Models Code**

```
namespace APP.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Lead
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LeadName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }  //User is another entity in APP.Models
    }
}
```

**API Code**

```
namespace APIProject.API
{
    public class IssueLogController : ApiController
    {
        CRMEntities db = new CRMEntities();

        [ResponseType(typeof(Lead))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLead(Lead lead)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Lead.Add(lead);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (LeadExists(lead.ID))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = lead.ID }, lead);
        }

    }
}
```

**Xamarin.Forms code**

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
            lead.LeadName = txtLead.Text.Trim();

        var uri = Constants.URL + "Lead/PostLead/";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

        var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lead, s);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Message", "Your Lead has been recorded.", "OK");
        }
```

Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Not with the info you're providing. A bad request means that you are sending bad data to the API. But depending on how the API is built this could be anything. Ranging from a deserialization error, to you throwing a Bad Request from code yourself. Please include some code and try to be more clear on what you are trying to do. Please also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: added code. I think it is related to serialization issue where the FK entity User is conflicting between API.Models & APP.Models

Comment: It's probably due to the BadRequest thrown after `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`. Ergo; the `ModelState` is not valid. Put in a breakpoint there, check the `ModelState` properties to see what is wrong.

Comment: For some unwanted reasons, I am unable to debug my application locally  and have to use a staging server. cant debug :(

Comment: In that case output the right property of the `ModelState` to the logs or turn it into a `return Ok(ModelState.Errors);` so you will know what is wrong. the `Errors` property is just a guess. Not sure from the top of my head what the property is that holds the validation errors.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. Do you think the approach used by me to share models between API/APP is correct?

Comment: It seems kind of redundant since they are _exactly_ the same. But remember: there is no correct way. It all depends on your requirements and needs. If the models will remain identical, why not move them to a common library and use them in both projects?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks, your comment helped.

Comment: Great! Best of luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gerald in comments above, here is what I did in the API code to figure out the error -

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var state in ModelState)
            {
                foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            t_app_issueLog.ID = 1;
            t_app_issueLog.Problem = sb.ToString();
            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = lead.ID }, lead);
            //return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```